# problems initializing my java method using node-java

Tags: java, node-java

I'm not a java jock, but I'm trying to learn how to use node-java. I tried to run one of the examples listed on npm java and gethub node-java and they don't work. I think my method is not initialize in my node.js script correctly. I'm using JDK/JRE 1.8 on a Window 10 laptop. Below is my simple code example. Any help would be appreciated.

```
var Test = java.import("com.sample.SearchQueryRulesFromTable");

var result = Test.SearchQueryRulesFromTable("C1", "P1");
console.log(result);
```

Error in node-java

```
nodeJavaBridge.js:233
return java.newInstanceSync.apply(java, args);
                            ^
 TypeError: Could not find method
"com.sample.SearchQueryRulesFromTable(java.lang.String,   
java.lang.String)" on class "class com.sample.SearchQueryRulesFromTable".
Possible matches:  
public com.sample.SearchQueryRulesFromTable() at Error (native)
at javaClassConstructorProxy….
```

Here is part of my java code:

```
...
public class SearchQueryRulesFromTable {
...
public static final void main(String[] args) {...
```

Results of javap

```
Compiled from "SearchQueryRulesFromTable.java
public class com.sample.SearchQueryRulesFromTable {
  public com.sample.SearchQueryRulesFromTable();
    descriptor: ()V

  public static final void main(java.lang.String[]);
    descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
}
```

@AlphaVictor I have tried to call the main method using node-java constructs that didn't seem to work. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Below is the main method in SearchQueryRulesFromTable:

```
ItemSearch  item1 = new ItemSearch();

item1.setSearchCustomer(args[0]);
item1.setSearchItem(args[1]);
```

Using:

```
java.callStaticMethodSync("com.sample.SearchQueryRulesFromTable", 
"ItemSearch(item1)","C1", "P1", function(err, results) {    
if(err) {console.error(err); 
javaLangSystem.out.printlnSync('test complete! '+ results);return;}
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\rdouglas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\NewProjects\08-
egilerapp1\classes>node test.js
(node) sys is deprecated. Use util instead.
C:\Users\rdouglas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\NewProjects\08-
egilerapp1\classes\test.js:14
var result = 
java.callStaticMethodSync("com.sample.SearchQueryRulesFromTable",  
 "ItemSearch","C1", "P1")
              ^
```

Error:

```
Could not find method "ItemSearch(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)" on
class "class com.sample.SearchQueryRulesFromTable". No methods with that
name.
at Error (native)
at Object.<anonymous>
(C:\Users\rdouglas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\NewProjects\08-
egilerapp1\classes\test.js:14:19)
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
at startup (node.js:139:18)
at node.js:968:3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TypeError: Could not find method
"com.sample.SearchQueryRulesFromTable(java.lang.String,   
java.lang.String)" on class "class com.sample.SearchQueryRulesFromTable".
```

This error tells you that you have tried to call a constructor on class `SearchQueryRulesFromTable` that accepts two `String` arguments. There is no such constructor defined on that class.

Your code is attempting to call this non-existent constructor here:

```
SearchQueryRulesFromTable("C1", "P1");
```

Depending on what you are trying to do, you may want to call the `main` method within `SearchQueryRulesFromTable` instead, and pass it a `String[]`.